# How do I run the InSpec using a wrapper profile?

Tags: chef, inspec

This blog post describes wrapper profiles in detail:

https://blog.chef.io/2017/07/06/understanding-inspec-profile-inheritance/

At the very end of the post, it references a Git repo that contains an example of using a wrapper profile:

https://github.com/adamleff/inspec-profile-wrapper-example

When I clone the repo, cd to the `controls` folder, and attempt to run these tests:

```
inspec exec controls_from_other_profiles.rb
```

I get the following error message:

> Cannot load linux-baseline since it is not listed as a dependency of
>   tests from controls_from_other_profiles.rb.
>
> Dependencies available from this context are:

The dependencies are defined in `inspec.yml`.

How do I correctly run these tests?

Comment: Don't try to run the control file but run the profile itself, there's pretty good material to learn inspec on https://learn.chef.io

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across the answer.  From within the profile directory, run this command:

```
inspec exec .
```

Don't forget to set the `depends` key in `inspec.yml`.